# Error while pushing to github for the first time "remote: Internal Server Error"

Tags: github

I cloned git repository and tried to push my changes but I facing the following issue;

When I do : git push origin master, i get the error:

```
remote: Internal Server Error 
To https://github.com...
! [remote rejected] master -> master (Internal Server Error)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com...'
```

Comment: https://www.githubstatus.com/

Comment: Github is having some technical issues right now, nothing you can do about it but keep an eye on https://githubstatus.com